# implement queue system with RxJs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

We have implemented a queue system in Javascript.

Consumers log items and internally it is inserted into a queue (which is an array stored in session storage).

A time interval is used to dequeue a number of items and to send these items to the backend.

How can we implement this using Rxjs and streams?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const queue = new Rx.Subject();

const queueProcessing = queue
  .mergeMap(i => Rx.Observable.of(i)
              .do(val => console.log('processing item: ' + val))
              .delay(2000) /* stub processing time*/
           , 2) /* concurrency */
  .subscribe();

queue.next('asdf');
queue.next('as');
queue.next('zxvc');
queue.next('`1`');
queue.next('zx');
queue.next('234');
queue.next('5');
queue.next('645');
queue.next('asdf');
queue.next('3');
queue.next('2');
queue.next('34');
queue.next('asdf');
queue.next('5');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

The `.mergeMap` contains a demo 'processing' function which just emits the value after a delay. Every time you want to add an item to the queue you `.next()` it into the subject.

Comment: The queue itself should be a wrapper over session storage (items are put in session storage). Then it should take 10 items from that queue every 2 seconds.

Comment: Why the requirement to have them be put in session storage? Do you want to retain the queue over requests? Because a non-streaming datastructure (in session storage, array) mixed with a streaming datastructure will work but can become complex and error prone quickly

Comment: Hi Mark, say I want a queue where only 3 items are being processed asynchronously at any one time, how do I go about this?

This is what I mean: If I have a collection of items to upload to the backend and I don't want to 
1. async/await each one before the next
2. Send everything off - this could lead to write hot-spotting or rate limiting
3. Do a promise.race, because this eventually leads to (2)
4. Do a promise.all, because then the process becomes slow if there's one long running upload.
And what I want to do is:
1. Have a queue of all the uploads with a stack of 3 items at a time

Comment: 2. When one item leaves the stack, we add a new item to the queue
3. At any one point, there are always 3 items in the stack.

How would I go about this in a bid to extend your solution?

Comment: @ChukwumaNwaugha check the concurrency param of mergeMap, in my example set to 2 but can be set to `n`

Comment: Yeah, thanks @MarkvanStraten. I was able to resolve it with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608353/implement-a-queueing-system-with-a-fixed-stack-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 0):

The operator you are looking for is [bufferTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffertime.html)

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { bufferTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

const queue$ = new Subject();
const interval = 2000; // 2 seconds

queue$.pipe(bufferTime(interval))
    .subscribe(queueArray => {
        // Send to backend
        console.log(queueArray);
    });

queue$.next('hello');
queue$.next('world');

// After 2 seconds logs: ['hello', 'world']
```