# implement a queueing system with a fixed stack in RxJs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, queue, rxjs6

Say I want a queue where only 3 items are being processed asynchronously at any one time, how do I go about this?

**This is what I mean:** If I have a collection of items to upload to the backend i.e. upload some artefacts to cloud storage and consequently create/update a doc to reflect the url of each artefact and **I don't want to:**

1. Async/Await each upload operation before the next - as this would be slow
2. Send everything off at the same time - this could lead to write hot-spotting or rate limiting
3. Do a promise.race - this eventually leads to (2)
4. Do a promise.all - the process becomes slow if there's one long running upload.

**And what I want to do is:**

1. Have a queue of all the uploads, say with an RxJs create method e.g. `from(array-of-upload-items)` with a stack of 3 items being processed at any one time.
2. And when one item leaves the stack i.e. completes, we add a new item to the queue
3. Ensure that at any one point, there are always 3 items in the stack being processed until there are no more items in the queue waiting to be put in the stack.

How would I go about this using RxJs?

**EDITED: 27/June/2020**

Here's what I am thinking of:

```
 const rxQueue = from(filesArray) // this is the list of files to upload say like 25 files or so

      rxQueue
        .pipe(
          mergeMap((item) =>
            of(item).pipe(
              tap(async (item) => {
                  await Promise.race([
                      processUpload(item[0]),
                      processUpload(item[1]),
                      processUpload(item[2]),
                  ])
              }),
            ),
            3
          ),
        )
        .subscribe()
```

The goal is to ensure that at any point, 3 files are being processed (uploaded) so much so that if one file upload process ends, another file is added to keep the stack at 3 upload processes. Same way, if 2 file uploads end at the same time, 2 new files are added to the stack and so on until all the files in the file array are uploaded.

Comment: Have you considered `mergeMap`'s third argument? `mergeMap(() => obs$, null, 3)`

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGătej I appreciate the swift response. Please see the edit/update in the Question for more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try this:

```js
from(filesArray)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(file => service.uploadFile(file), 3)
  )
```

This assumes that `service.uploadFile` returns a promise or an observable.

Let's say you have 5 files, then 3 observables will be created from the first 3 and when one of them completes, the 4th file will be taken and a new observable will be created from it and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Subject` as queue and with `mergeMap` there's a concurrency param that you can limit max number of concurrency

```
const queue=new Subject()
queque.asObservable().pipe(mergeMap(item=>httpCall(item),3)
queue.next(item)
```

Comment: Thanks @FanCheung I appreciate the swift response. Please see the edit/update in the Question for more context.

Comment: thanks so much for this answer, it solves it exactly as I need it. Please permit me to choose @AndreiGătej response as the answer since his initial response came first and was correct, just that I didn't really get what he was pointing at then. I'll wait for your confirmation before choosing his response as the answer. Thanks so much

Comment: No worry feel free